# MFC - C++ - CToolBar::SetState (ID, TBSTATE_INDETERMINATE)

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am developing a Windows Application using MFC with the use of C++.

I have a toolbar, which I want to control dynamically. In the MainFrame, based on some if else condition, I want to disable (gray out) or enable the toolbar entries, which is perfectly working fine. i.e. The toolbar entry is (also, remains) grayed out, when the condition is not met. And, vice versa holds true as well (i.e. as soon as the condition is met, it is again enabled). So far so good.

Example Code: I didn't include `MESSAGE_MAP or ONCOMMAND or the corresponding Action Functions` of the Toolbar entries for brevity.

In MainFrame.CPP

```
if(....) 
    m_wndToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetState
        (ID_SIMULATION_START, TBSTATE_INDETERMINATE); 
else
    m_wndToolBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetState
        (ID_SIMULATION_START, TBSTATE_ENABLED);
```

The Problem is, when I move the mouse over the toolbar entries, the entries become visible again. If I click the entries when it is grayed out, the action methods are getting called, which I want to avoid.

PS: Other operations like undock/dock/move works fine.

Comment: You don't show it, but, are you using the ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI mechanism to do this?  If not, you should be.

Comment: Ok, now it behaves as expected. If I dock the toolbar in CBRS_LEFT, it behaves in a weird way. Some icons suddenly disabled or hidden. If I undock/position it in other regions, then there is no problem with the behaviour.

Comment: Ok, now it behaves as expected. If I dock the toolbar in CBRS_LEFT, it behaves in a weird way. Some icons suddenly disabled or hidden. If I undock/position it in other regions, then there is no problem with the behaviour.

Comment: did you change your code to delete your `SetState()` calls and start using `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` as @rrirower suggested? this [MSDN forum entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/40adc8f2-c8a3-479d-b96c-07e770d0cbb3/problem-in-enable-and-disable-toolbar?forum=vcgeneral) gives some details, that might help